# Question about a property of equivalence relations when showing an induced map is well-defined in questions concerning proof of coequalizers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, proof-explanation

The following is taken from "Categories" by T.S.Blyth

$\color{green}{Background}$

Let $E$ be a non-empty set and let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $E.$  Consider the category $C$ whose objects are pairs $(X,f)$ where $X$ is a non-empty set and $f:E\to X$ is a mapping such that $xRy \Longrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$  (in other words, such that $R$ implies $R_f$ where $R_f$ is the equivalence relation on $E$ associated with $f$).  Define $\text{Mor}_C((X,f),(Y,g))$ to be the set of all mappings $h:X\to Y$ such that $h\circ f=g:$

$\textbf{Example 1:}$

[image]

We claim that the set $E/R$ of $R-$classes together with the natural map $\sharp_R:E\to E/R,$ described by $\sharp_R(x)=[x]_R,$ is an initial object in $C.$  To see this; let $g:E\to Y$ be such that $xRy\Longrightarrow g(x)=g(y).$ This means that we have $\sharp_R(x)=\sharp_R(y)\Longrightarrow g(x)=g(y)$ and so we can define a mapping $h:E/R\to Y$ by setting $h([x]_R)=g(x).$  Clearly, we have $h\circ \sharp_R=g.$  That $h$ is unique with respect to this property follows from the fact that if $k$ is also such that $k\circ \sharp_R=g$ then, since $\sharp_R$ is surjective, hence epic, we obtain $k=h$ by right cancellation.

$\textbf{Example 2:}$

Given $f,g:A\to B$ in $\textbf{Set}, \textbf{Grp}$ or $_R\textbf{Mod}$ let $Q$ be the smallest equivalence relation (respectively, congruence) on $B$ such that $$(\forall a\in A)(f(a)\equiv g(a)\quad(Q).$$

Consider $B/Q$ endowed with the appropriate structure.  Then the natural morphism $\sharp_Q:B\to B/Q$ is a coequaliser of $f,g.$  To see this, observe first from the definition of $Q$ that $\sharp_Q\circ f=\sharp_Q\circ g.$  Suppose now that $j:B\to X$ is such that $j\circ f\equiv j\circ g.$  If $R_j$ is the associated equivalence relation (respectively, congruence) we have that $$(\forall a\in A)f(a)\equiv g(a)\quad (R_f)$$ so that, by definition, $Q$ implies $R_j.$  It now follows from the universal property of $B/Q$ described in $\textbf{Example 1}$ that there is a unique morphism $k:B/Q\to X$ such that the diagram

[image]

is commutative.  Consequently $\sharp_Q:B\to B/Q$ is a coequaliser of $f,g.$

$\color{blue}{Questions}$

What I would like to know is how does $Q$ implies $R_j.$  Am I correct to understand that $Q$ and $R_j$ are separate equivalence relations being defined on $B.$  If given two separate equivalence relations, to show that $k\circ \sharp_Q=j$ is well defined.  Then we need the assumption $b_1Qb_2\Longrightarrow j(b_1)=j(b_2)?$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The part "Suppose now that $j: B\to X$  is such that $j\circ f = j\circ g$." means that $j$ satisfies $\forall a\in A: j(f(a) = j(g(a))$ which in turn means that $R_j$ satisfies $\forall a\in A: f(a) \equiv  g(a) (R_j)$.

Because $Q$ was definined as the smallest equivalence (resp. congruence) that satisfies this property, you have $Q \subseteq R_j$.

Comment: @MarcOlschok I want to ask since the proof did not really show this,... to show that $k\circ \sharp_Q([b])=j(b)$ is a well defined function.  Do I need to explicitly spell you the assumption: $b_1Qb_2\Longrightarrow j(b_1)=j(b_2)?$

Comment: Yes. After all the map $k$ is basically define via elements of $B$.  So in order that $k([b]) := j(b)$ does not depend on the equivalence class of $b\in B$ the implication $b_1 Q b_2 \Rightarrow j(b_1) = j(b_2)$ is needed.

Comment: @MarcOlschok oh kk, thank you for clearing that up for me.